# Why is this button not changing text in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, button

I need this button to change from "$5 USD" to "$10 USD" through the means of activating a function from a different button. I have updated the question to include more html and css information since uploading it. Here is the button whose text needs to be changed, and the button that activates said change:

```js
function increase() {
  document.getElementById("money").value = "$10 USD";
}
```

```css
.fader1{
  -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; 
}
.dog{
  -webkit-animation: fadein 8s;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
}
.fader2{
  -webkit-animation: fadein 8s; 
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
h1{
  font-size:320%;
}
h2{
  font-size:200%;
}
div{
  text-align:center;
}
button,
#money{
  width:20%;
  height:150px;
  font-size:120%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1 class="fader1">Increase payment?</h1>
    <img class="dog" src="https://i.imgur.com/BAz7AGU.jpg">
      <div class="fader2">
        <input id="money" type="button" value="$5 USD" />
        <button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have updated this question as changing `innerHTML` to `value` did not change the outcome, so I hoped more context would help.

Comment: Inputs don't have `innerHTML`, you need to set `value`

Comment: Also, there's no `</input>`. Inputs are self-closing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue

Comment: I did an edit of your code, run the snippet and you will see that things are now working. If not for you, than it is becauase you have not linked your JS correctly. I also added a /> to the end of your input.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to set the value of the input. Try this:

```js
function increase() {
  document.getElementById("money").value = "$10 USD";
}
```

```html
<input id="money" type="button" value="$5 USD">
<button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
```

---

## Update after question edit:

It seems like you haven't linked your `js` code with `html`. If you open the [developer console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) in your browser, you will get a reference error: `ReferenceError: increase is not defined`. That means your `html` doesn't know about the `increase()` function you have written.

You could fix that in a couple of ways.

The easiest one would be to add it directly to the html, in the `script` tag:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- your other code -->
    </div>
    <script>
        function increase() {
            document.getElementById("money").value = "$10 USD";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

---

The recommended way of doing it is linking the `.js` file, in which you will write the function, to the `.html` file:

`.html` file:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- your other code -->
    </div>
    <script src="main.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

`main.js` file:

```
function increase() {
  document.getElementById("money").value = "$10 USD";
}
```

Comment: I have changed ```innerHTML``` to ```value```, yet the text still does not change.

Comment: Have you tried my code snippet? It works there. You might be missing something else in your code outside SO

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question to include the ```value``` change. I hope more context will make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change line 2 of your JS from `.innerHTML` to `.value`
2. Not sure how your script is linked but try moving `<script></script>` to your HTML footer to ensure DOM is fully loaded before the JS function attempts to select the button element
3. If still not working, check your console for any errors